# How to dynamically link GCC objects?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, linker

I'm unsure if the question is phrased correctly, or if what I want to is possible.

I have an existing GCC application (compiled for a Cortex-M3 if that matters). What I want to do is create a little piece of functionality (just a single method, few methods) that can call into the existing application.

I want to place these few methods at a specific memory location (I know how to do that). What I don't know how to do is get the new application to compile/link with the objects of the existing application.

For instance, my existing application has the function:

```
int Add(int a, int b);
```

And new application wants to use it:

```
int Calculate(int a, int b, int opType)
{
  Add(a, b);
}
```

I have access to all linker, obj, h files, etc.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve... You can of course always link, when building your app, with a static or shared library. Are you trying to link with some shared library or runtime? If so, take a look at the 'dl' functions (dlopen, dlsym, etc.)... Or just clarify the question...

Comment: What system is your Cortex-M3 running?  If it's a custom OS or a small RTOS, there's a good chance you will have to implement your own dynamic linking/loading capability. Depending on your needs, it could be pretty simple (if you just need to load items that are at fixed addresses and are already linked to be located at those addresses) or it can be more complex if you need to handle address fixups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your input, however I was able to do exactly what I wanted by compiling the new application using the ELF file from the existing application has an input to the Linker by specifying
`--just-symbols elffile.elf`

Answer (score 4):

You can't usually link to *executables*, only libraries (static or shared) and object files. So, the best advice I can give would be to build the "core" of the first program as a shared library, and link the "front-end" (`main`) as an executable built against the core shared lib. Then, your second program can also just be a program linked against the shared library.

You can also use `dlopen` on dynamic executables to link the executable at runtime, and use `dlsym` to get function pointers for the desired functionality, though this is usually only used if you have no control over the first executable.

Example of the latter (note again that this should be a last resort):

a.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("hello world!\n"); return 42; }
```

b.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

main() {
    void *handle = dlopen("a", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!handle) {
        printf("failed: %s\n", dlerror());
        return -1;
    }
    int (*amain)() = dlsym(handle, "main");
    if(!amain) {
        printf("dlsym failed: %s\n", dlerror());
        return -1;
    }
    return amain();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Why is the option of using `dlsym` a last resort?

Comment: You should not normally be `dlopen`ing executables. A proper library of reusable code will be shipped as a library, not as an executable. If you are forced to link against an executable, that's a sign that you may want to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a linux variant, then the answer given by @nneonneo to use dlopen() and dlsym() is the best approach.

However, assuming that you're using another OS (or none at all) and/or you really really need this code to live at a fixed location (for example if you need to shift execution to an address on a specific memory device, eg. if doing flash manipulation), you can use a hard coded function pointer.

Declare a function pointer as follows:

```
typedef int (*AddFnPtr)(int a, int b);
AddFnPtr MyAddFunction = (AddFnPtr)ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_FUNCTION;
```

Then call as:

```
int Calculate(int a, int b, int opType)
{
  MyAddFunction(a, b);
}
```

Note that the linker has no way of knowing if the code that you've put at that location has the right prototype, or even exists - so there is no error checking either at link time or at run time.

You will probably (depending on OS) also need to take steps to map the absolute memory location at which you've put your function into the local processes address space.